# Draw this image in the TIKZ package

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I need to draw this image using TikZ.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I've changed your Portuguese request to English, which is the language of the site. But questions which just post an image and ask people to draw it for you are really not the best way to ask a question. Much of this diagram is quite simple, so can you edit your question to include a minimal document that shows at least some of what you've tried. Then we could help you with what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to build this figure that uses several key concepts from TikZ:

- the `scope`
- `clip`
- the use of the `intersections` library
- the use of `node` to place text.
- `sloped` to write text tangent to a path

Their use is explained in the written comments in the code.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% This scope allows you to draw the part of the circle inside the rectangle. The outer part is cut off.
\begin{scope}% use of intersections library to define the intersections between circle and rectangle
\draw[name path global=cadre,clip] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,4.5);
\draw[name path global=cercle] (3.5,0)circle(4.6cm);
\end{scope}

% draw both sides of the angular sector
\draw[name intersections={of=cercle and cadre}](intersection-2)--(3.5,0)--(intersection-1)node[above right,midway]{h};

% sloped allow to write text tangent to the path
\path[above] (intersection-1)to[bend left=15]node[sloped]{$c(h)$}(intersection-2);

% dimension of rectangle wrtien in 2 differents way
\draw [<->](4.2,0)--node[right]{q}(4.2,4.5);
\draw [<->](0,-.6)--(3.5,-.6)node[below,midway]{p};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using a `local bounding box` saves us from a lot of hassle here.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[fill,inner sep=1.5pt,circle] (O) at (0,0){};
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=box]
    \draw (O.center) -- (100:4) arc(100:140:4) node[pos=0.7,above,sloped,inner
    xsep=0pt] {$c(h)$}
    -- node[midway,below] {$h$} cycle;
   \end{scope}  
   \draw (box.south west) rectangle (box.north east);
   \draw[|-|] (1,0|-box.south) -- (1,0|-box.north)node[midway,fill=white]{$p$};
   \draw[|-|] (0,-1 -|box.west) -- (0,-1 -|box.east)node[midway,fill=white]{$q$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the use of the `local bounding box`. You can simplify the drawing of the lengths p and q :    `\draw[|-|] (1,0)node{a} -- (1,0|-box.north)node[midway,fill=white]{$p$};
   \draw[|-|] (0,-1 -|box.west) -- (0,-1)node[midway,fill=white]{$q$};`

Answer (score 7):

A PSTricks solution just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[arrowinset=0](-5,-1)(1,5.5)
    \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none,PosAngle=-45](0,0){S}
    \pnodes(5;150){A}(5;100){B}
    \pswedge(S){5}{(B)}{(A)}
    \psframe(A|S)(S|B)
    \rput{0}(5.4;130){$c(h)$}
    \pcline(A)(S)\ncput*{$h$}
    \pcline[offset=-.5]{|<->|}(A|S)(S)\ncput*{$p$}
    \pcline[offset=.5]{|<->|}(S|B)(S)\ncput*{$q$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: + 1 for {(B)}{(A)}

Answer (score 3):

Here you go :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1,line width=0.75pt]
    \draw   (46.5,25) -- (145.5,25) -- (145.5,156.33) -- (46.5,156.33) -- cycle ;
    \draw    (46.5,176.33) -- (145.5,176.33) ;
    \draw [shift={(145.5,176.33)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (0,5.59) -- (0,-5.59)(10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9)   ;
    \draw [shift={(46.5,176.33)}, rotate = 0] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (0,5.59) -- (0,-5.59)(10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
    \draw    (165.5,156.33) -- (165.5,25) ;
    \draw [shift={(165.5,25)}, rotate = 450] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (0,5.59) -- (0,-5.59)(10.93,-4.9) .. controls (6.95,-2.3) and (3.31,-0.67) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.67) and (6.95,2.3) .. (10.93,4.9)   ;
    \draw [shift={(165.5,156.33)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (0,5.59) -- (0,-5.59)(10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
    \draw    (46.88,52.66) -- (145.5,156.33) ;
    \draw    (117.77,25) -- (145.5,156.33) ;
    \draw  [draw opacity=0] (46.88,52.66) .. controls (65.27,35.5) and (89.95,25) .. (117.08,25) .. controls (117.31,25) and (117.54,25) .. (117.77,25) -- (117.08,127.92) -- cycle ; \draw   (46.88,52.66) .. controls (65.27,35.5) and (89.95,25) .. (117.08,25) .. controls (117.31,25) and (117.54,25) .. (117.77,25) ;

    % Text Nodes
    \draw (99,163) node  [align=left] {$\displaystyle p$};
    \draw (174,91) node  [align=left] {$\displaystyle q$};
    \draw (101,96) node  [align=left] {$\displaystyle h$};
    \draw (153,160) node  [align=left] {$\displaystyle s$};
    \draw (82,40) node [scale=0.8] [align=left] {$\displaystyle c( h)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And do you really want to set a style for  `every picture`? This will affect all other `tikzpictures`, which is probably not desirable.

Comment: @Superuser27: your code is from Geogebra, right?

Comment: No @BlackMild I drew it with Matcha, why? :)